# Adjoints to Forgetful Functor

Tags: category-theory

Suppose $C$ is a category, $X\in C$. I want to find minimal conditions on $C$ for which the forgetful functor $U:C/X\rightarrow C$ has a left adjoint.

edit: As pointed out in the comments, $U$ has no left adjoint unless $X$ is terminal which then says that $C$ and $C/X$ are isomorphic.

I did manage to produce a right adjoint by defining $G:C\rightarrow C/X$ on objects: $A\rightarrow (\pi _{2}:A\times X\rightarrow X)$ and on morphisms $\overline f:A\rightarrow S$ by $G(\overline f)=\overline f\times 1_{X}$, where $\overline f\times 1_{X}$ is the arrow in $C/X)$ from $\pi _{2}:A\times X\rightarrow X$ to $p _{2}:S\times X\rightarrow X$ So if 
\begin{array}{&&} 
A & \stackrel{f}{\to} & S\times X \\
& h \searrow & \downarrow p_{2} \\ 
 & & X 
\end{array} is an arrow in $C/X$, then we obtain a unique $\overline f:U(A,h)=A\rightarrow S$ using the UMP of the product $A\times S$. More specifically, $\overline f$ is the unique morphism such that $p_{1}f=\overline f$ and $p_{2}f=h$. The unit $\eta :1_{C/X}\rightarrow GU$ is determined uniquely, again, by the UMP of the product $A\times X$: $\pi {_1}\eta _{(A,h)}=1_{A}$ and $\pi {_2}\eta _{(A,h)}=h$
. 
So $U$ has a right adjoint if and only if $C$ has products of type $A\times X$. My question is: is there an easier way to show this? I did it basically from scratch. I wonder if there is a slick way to do it.

Comment: This seems really unlikely. At a minimum $U$ needs to preserve limits, and I already don't see any reason $U$ should preserve products (usually the natural map from fiber products to products is not an isomorphism). Usually a functor like $U$ has a right adjoint, and sometimes that right adjoint will also have a right adjoint. See http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/base+change .

Comment: $U$ preserves terminal objects if and only if $X$ is terminal. So a necessary and sufficient condition is that $X$ is terminal.

Comment: @Zhen: I actually tried to construct the unit for the possible adjunction and was able to do it only if $X$ was terminal, as you say. And this case is not interesting right because then $C/X$ is isomprphic to $C$. So the bottom line is, $U$ does not have a left adjoint.